# Rake task working on local machine, not on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Here is my simple rake task :

```
desc 'Create objects from csv'
  task :add_missing_information_from_url, [:url] => [:environment] do |t, args|
    url = args[:url]

    puts "STARTED"

    CSV.new(open(url), :headers => :first_row).to_enum.with_index(1).each do |line, i|
      user = User.find(line['id'])
      next if user.nil?

      user.flag = true
      user.save

      puts "#{i} - #{user.firstname}"
    end
  end
```

For starters doesn't do anything smart. But for some reason this doesn't work on Heroku. This is how I execute the task (my namespace is dbs):

```
heroku run rake dbs:add_missing_information_from_url['http://lvh.me/file.csv']
```

Or on dev machine :

```
bundle exec rake dbs:add_missing_information_from_url['http://lvh.me/file.csv']
```

This is the only output I get from the console when running heroku task :

```
Running `rake dbs:add_missing_information_from_url[http://lvh.me/file.csv]` attached to terminal... up, run.7246
```

And returns to my shell after it has executed with nothing printed, nor the user objects get saved.

However when I run it on my dev machine, all works fine, starting by printing `STARTED` onwards.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Is it me or does your log actually outputs this :

```
Running `rake dbs:add_missing_information_from_url[http://lvh.me/file.csv]` attached to terminal... up, run.7246
```

If you take a closer look at the argument in the `[http://lvh.me/file.csv]`, it appears not to be a string. You would want your log to output `['http://lvh.me/file.csv']`.

So I suggest you try running your task like this :

```
heroku run rake dbs:add_missing_information_from_url['"http://lvh.me/file.csv"']
```